QGis set polygon color according to vertex z value
Using Qgis, I have one multipolygonZ layer which representing underground gallery.
As you can see on the following picture, the red one corresponds to the upper floor gallery all vertex z value is set to 2, for the pink one z are set to 0.

Inside my black cirle i would like a ramp color according to the elevation of my polygons (i manually change my vertices to be linear from 0 to 2).
Is anyone has an idea about it ? (I search a solution for several weeks)

easiest way would be to create a third layer with gradient fill for the ramp part...
